# flsh component slider with as3 class--huh?

Tags: actionscript-3, slider

attempting to add a flash component slider to my as 3 class and I cant find any examples on the web.  I am surprised at the number of funky home made sliders i am seeing.  Maybe there is a problem with flash components and as 3?  Could you leave a note if this is doable, and any rough direction you could provide.  thnks!!

Comment: I believe if you include the correct SWCs in your actionscript project you can use the built in fl.controls.Slider class but you still don't have the source code for it, my guess is this is why most people (self included) just roll our own.

Comment: It seems this would come up often, BUT there is zero about this on the web.  Amazing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The examples in the [AS3 docs](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/fl/controls/Slider.html#includeExamplesSummary) should give you the information you need.

Reasons not to use the slider component:

- It adds 32KB to the size of your SWF. Not a great option where file size is critical.
- It's not that difficult to code a slider which may be more suitable to your needs.

I wouldn't be (haven't been) afraid to use the built-in slider component, though.

Comment: Thanks, I just did another 3 hr google hunt on this.  32KB does not seem like much of a hit, esp since most custom sliders look like awful. The meta issue is getting a class to listen to a stage object. Maybe I should investigate despatch/broadcast strategies. thanks

Comment: hi T Graham--so the key thing i was missing was using my Main class as a document class. I do not see an accept button anywhere--i'll figure that out.  Thanks for your helpful link.

Answer (score 0):

You do need to make sure the component is in your FLA library before compiling.  Including the code in your AS will not do since I beleive Flash needs all of the visual elements present.